# Assign a static IP to a node in GCP k8 cluster

Tags: kubernetes, ip, devops, google-kubernetes-engine, gcloud

I have this client that needs our static IP addresses in order to allow me to access their API's so that they could whitelist my IPs.

The problem is that our services are running in a k8 cluster in GCP and our external IP Addresses which are the IP Addresses of the cluster nodes, are managed by GCP's GKE, and the nodes are created/destroyed as they scale in the cluster. How can I assign a static IP to the nodes? it doesn't even make sense to do it in this scenario or what would be the best approach to solve it.

Is even possible to assign a static IP to a node of k8 cluster?

Comment: See [Set up Cloud NAT with GKE](https://cloud.google.com/nat/docs/gke-example)

Comment: thanks so much @DazWilkin this is indeed the way to do it!

Comment: Just a reminder that when you assign a static IP for your nodes, autohealing and autoscaling feature of a GKE cluster may fail. See [1] 

[1] https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ip-addresses/reserve-static-external-ip-address#disableexternalip

Comment: Caution: Restricting external IPs to specific VMs can prevent existing GKE clusters and managed instance groups (MIGs) from adding new VMs. If a GKE cluster or a MIG is configured to create VMs that have external IP addresses, autohealing and autoscaling actions fail.